# Terraform create app service for linux container

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I everyone.
I am trying to use terraform to create a azure app service for my docker images, but apparently this resource get created for windows by default even if my `app_service_plan`is configured to be for a linux environment.
My configuration are as follow:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "ASP-name" {
  location = var.location
  name = "ASP-name"
  resource_group_name = <resource-group>
  is_xenon = false
  kind = "Linux"
  maximum_elastic_worker_count = 1
  per_site_scaling = false
  reserved = true
  sku {
    capacity = 1
    size = "P1v2"
    tier = "PremiumV2"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "app-name" {
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.ASP-name.id
  location = var.location
  name = "app-name"
  resource_group_name = <resource-group>
  app_settings = {
    ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Production"
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD"           = "value"
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL"                = "value"
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME"           = "value"
  }
  client_affinity_enabled = false
  client_cert_enabled = false
  enabled = true

}
```

Can please somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This sample](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/tree/master/examples/app-service/docker-basic) provisions a Linux App Service that runs a single Docker container. You need to provide your docker image with `linux_fx_version`.

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "ASP-name" {
  location = var.location
  name = "ASP-name"
  resource_group_name = <resource-group>

  kind = "Linux"
  maximum_elastic_worker_count = 1
  per_site_scaling = false
  reserved = true
  sku {
    capacity = 1
    size = "P1v2"
    tier = "PremiumV2"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "app-name" {
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.ASP-name.id
  location = var.location
  name = "app-name"
  resource_group_name = <resource-group>

  site_config {
  app_command_line = ""
  linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|appsvcsample/python-helloworld:latest"
}

  app_settings = {
   
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD"           = "value"
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL"                = "value"
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME"           = "value"
  }
  client_affinity_enabled = false
  client_cert_enabled = false
  enabled = true

}
```

Answer (score 4):

As the ressource `azurerm_app_service` is now depricated in the TF provider `azurerm` since v3.0 and will be remove in v4.0, the acceppted answer is not applicable anymore, because the new replacement resource `azurerm_linux_web_app` doesn't provide the `linux_fx_version` attribute.

Instead you need to set the full docker image URL inside `azurerm_linux_web_app` -> `site_config` -> `application_stack` -> `docker_image`

Here is an example provided using the `azurerm_container_registry` data source.

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "my-web-app" {
  name                = var.web-app-name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.my-resource-group.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.my-resource-group.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.my-service-plan.id

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      docker_image     = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.my-container-registry.login_server}/my-container-name"
      docker_image_tag = "latest"
    }
  }

  app_settings = {
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL      = data.azurerm_container_registry.my-container-registry.login_server
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME = data.azurerm_container_registry.my-container-registry.admin_username
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD = data.azurerm_container_registry.my-container-registry.admin_password
  }
}

data "azurerm_container_registry" "my-container-registry" {
  name                = var.docker-registry-name
  resource_group_name = var.docker-registry-resource-group
}
```